# The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Im working on react-native project i design to change the icons
i followed this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts98gL1JCQU

then the project cannt run and im getting error
[image]

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Remove Build Tools version and sync project
Affected Modules: rn-secure-storage

Just woundring what i should do , also i dont want rn-secure-storage be affected

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options :

1. Update Build Tools to 28.0.3 which is the minimum for you Gradle
2. Click "Remove buildtoolsversion 28.0.2" and Android will remove it from your Gradle